# Can a Solana Pay transaction request return more than the publickey of the wallet scanning the QR code?

Tags: solana

For example, how can we get the exact balances of specific SPL tokens from a wallet that scans a Solana Pay QR code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

import { getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount } from "@solana/spl-token";

https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-pay/blob/master/core/src/parseURL.ts#L78

After scanning QR code scan, parse the url you will get spl-token

```
  const tokenAcc = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
    provider.connection,
    owner,
    new anchor.web3.PublicKey(
      parsed_spl_token_from_qr_code
    ),
    provider.wallet.publicKey
  );

  const accInfo = await provider.connection.getTokenAccountBalance(
    tokenAcc.address
  );
  console.log(
    "Balance ",
    Number(accInfo.value.amount) / anchor.web3.LAMPORTS_PER_SOL
  );
```